# Wrong behavior of Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(str)

Tags: java, android, regex

I've beed using `Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(str)` in my app to validate the URLs in my app. This api works great in pre-Lollipop APIs. However, in Lollipop it is validating even "abd.def". Strange and buggy behavior. Any suggestions/idea of a fix?

Comment: I recommend reading: [Why I avoid android.util.Patterns](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/05/22/why-i-dont-use-patterns/).

Answer (score 7):

> Strange and buggy behavior

Using a firmware-baked regex is by definition "buggy".

The list of top-level domains (TLDs) has been steadily expanding. Any regex that tries to limit to known TLDs at that time will become out of date eventually. So, 12 months ago, Google engineers [changed the regex to accept any TLD, so long as it uses the proper characters](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a3bb66a75ef746fc77e9c9dd466afdef7a56996c%5E%21/#F0). The alternative is a never-ending series of bug reports about how valid URLs fail the regex, when those URLs would have been invalid when that version of Android shipped.

> Any suggestions/idea of a fix?

Write your own regex. Or, fork the older regex and maintain your own list of valid TLDs. Or, validate the URLs by some other means. Or, find somebody actively maintaining a library that allows you to do the same, where you make sure that you keep updating your use of the library to take into account new TLDs.

IOW, do something that is firmware-independent, and make sure you keep maintaining it to be accurate with respect to changes in valid TLDs.

Answer (score 3):

To expand upon CommonsWare's answer, here is what I use to avoid Linkify linking seemingly random text:

```
Linkify.TransformFilter filter = new Linkify.TransformFilter() {
        public final String transformUrl(final Matcher match, String url) {
            return match.group();
        }
    };

    Pattern webURL = Pattern.compile(new StringBuilder()
                    .append("((?:(http|https|Http|Https|rtsp|Rtsp):")
                    .append("\\/\\/(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\\$\\-\\_\\.\\+\\!\\*\\'\\(\\)")
                    .append("\\,\\;\\?\\&\\=]|(?:\\%[a-fA-F0-9]{2})){1,64}(?:\\:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\\$\\-\\_")
                    .append("\\.\\+\\!\\*\\'\\(\\)\\,\\;\\?\\&\\=]|(?:\\%[a-fA-F0-9]{2})){1,25})?\\@)?)?")
                    .append("((?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}\\.)+")   // named host
                    .append("(?:")   // plus top level domain
                    .append("(?:aero|arpa|asia|a[cdefgilmnoqrstuwxz])")
                    .append("|(?:biz|b[abdefghijmnorstvwyz])")
                    .append("|(?:cat|com|coop|c[acdfghiklmnoruvxyz])")
                    .append("|d[ejkmoz]")
                    .append("|(?:edu|e[cegrstu])")
                    .append("|f[ijkmor]")
                    .append("|(?:gov|g[abdefghilmnpqrstuwy])")
                    .append("|h[kmnrtu]")
                    .append("|(?:info|int|i[delmnoqrst])")
                    .append("|(?:jobs|j[emop])")
                    .append("|k[eghimnrwyz]")
                    .append("|l[abcikrstuvy]")
                    .append("|(?:mil|mobi|museum|m[acdghklmnopqrstuvwxyz])")
                    .append("|(?:name|net|n[acefgilopruz])")
                    .append("|(?:org|om)")
                    .append("|(?:pro|p[aefghklmnrstwy])")
                    .append("|qa")
                    .append("|r[eouw]")
                    .append("|s[abcdeghijklmnortuvyz]")
                    .append("|(?:tel|travel|t[cdfghjklmnoprtvwz])")
                    .append("|u[agkmsyz]")
                    .append("|v[aceginu]")
                    .append("|w[fs]")
                    .append("|y[etu]")
                    .append("|z[amw]))")
                    .append("|(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]") // or ip address
                    .append("[0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])\\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]")
                    .append("|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]|0)\\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]")
                    .append("[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]|0)\\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}")
                    .append("|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])))")
                    .append("(?:\\:\\d{1,5})?)") // plus option port number
                    .append("(\\/(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\\;\\/\\?\\:\\@\\&\\=\\#\\~")  // plus option query params
                    .append("\\-\\.\\+\\!\\*\\'\\(\\)\\,\\_])|(?:\\%[a-fA-F0-9]{2}))*)?")
                    .append("(?:\\b|$)").toString()
    );

    Linkify.addLinks(myTextView, webURL, null, null, filter);
```