# Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(urlStr).matches() not working above kitkat

Tags: android

I am using `Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(urlStr).matches()` to recognize url within string but its giving wrong result e.g "tomorrow.Sounds" is recognized as url.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770866/wrong-behavior-of-patterns-web-url-matcherstr