# Check if an URL is valid

Tags: java, android

So my code in android studio asks an user to for his login data:

```
String username = etUsername.getText.toString();
String password= etPassword.getText.toString();
```

If this is done i adds username and password to a String

```
String url = "https://test/testt.php?username="+username+"&password="+password;
```

After that I call the state with

```
state = Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches();
```

Don't know what is wrong but it returns true every time;

Comment: And why will it be wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770866/wrong-behavior-of-patterns-web-url-matcherstr

Comment: I returns true everytime

Comment: yes but if the username or the password is false it should return false

Comment: Do you mean that if a login/password pair is wrong, `Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher()` will return false?

Comment: Thats exactly correct

Comment: I suppose it should return `false` if a login is something like "   ...///?&   ". But if a login and password are valid, it should return `true` in any case.

Answer (score 3):

`Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher("https://test/testt.php?username=myusername&password=mypassword").matches()` should return true as its a valid syntax for an url.

This doesn't check if the url is active and accessible, it just checks if the provided string matches the syntax of an url. It doesn't call the url, it doesn't make a connection and it doesn't get any response.

Check https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection for one example of a way to retrieve a web page:

```
String url = "https://test/testt.php?username="+username+"&password="+password;
URL url = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try {
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    readStream(in);
} finally {
    urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

or use a library like [volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley) or [retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Comment: And what could I instead of this

Comment: @id3456903, you should use `Retrofit` and create a request, then parse a JSON.

Comment: Well, don't forget to add Internet permission in AndroidManifest and do download job in background thread.